# Why does calculating probability of 2 pairs seem so different from for a full house?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, poker

For 5 card poker without discards/draws, the probability of being dealt a 2 pair hand is about 0.047539, and for a full house is about 0.001441.  [1](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Eramsey/Probability/PokerHands.html)

---

I first learned about calculating for a 2 pair hand.  I incorrectly came up with:

$${
{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 2}{12\choose 1}{4\choose 2}{44\choose 1}}
\over{52\choose 5}}={{(13)(6)(12)(6)(44)}\over2598960}\approx0.095078$$

Notably, my answer is exactly double the correct answer.

I learned that the correct way to calculate this is to choose the 2 ranks together that will be the pairs:

$${
{{13\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{44\choose 1}}
\over{52\choose 5}}={{(78)(6)(6)(44)}\over2598960}\approx0.047539$$

---

So, later, I moved on to calculating for a full house.  I proudly remembered to choose the ranks together and incorrectly came up with:

$${
{{13\choose 2}{4\choose 3}{4\choose 2}}
\over{52\choose 5}}={{(78)(4)(6)}\over2598960}\approx0.000720$$

I learned that the correct way to calculate this is to choose the 2 ranks separately:

$${
{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{12\choose 1}{4\choose 2}}
\over{52\choose 5}}={{(13)(4)(12)(6)}\over2598960}\approx0.001441$$

---

Q1: For a 2 pair hand, why does choosing the ranks separately double count the possibilities?  Why must we choose the 2 ranks together (or divide by 2?)

Q2: When we move onto a full house, why does this change?  Why does choosing the ranks together under count the possibilities?  Why must we choose the 2 ranks separately (or multiply by 2?)

Q3: I'm having a surprisingly hard time grasping how to come up with these on my own.  Are there any tips or resources to help polish up these issues?

Comment: When you have a full house, you say “full house, kings and tens” means three kings and two tens. So “full house, tens and kings” means a different hand. “Two pairs, kings and tens” means the same thing as “Two pairs, tens and kings.”

Answer (score 3):

You double count in the first case, because the hand 4, 4, 7, 7, 9 is the same as 7, 7, 4, 4, 9. You have to fix the pair of which you will draw a second card each (like 4, 7 in this case).

Otoh the full house 5, 5, 5, 2, 2 is different from 2, 2, 2, 5, 5. You first fix the triple and then the pair.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake in the first case was you calculated as though assigning a value to one pair was distinct and different than assigning the value to the *other* pair.  As the pairs are both pairs it doesn't matter which of the two get each value.

Your mistake in the second case was you calculated as though assigning a value to the pair was the same and indistinguishable from assigning a value to the triple.  As the pair and the triple are distinct and different things is *does* matter which of the two get each value.

${13\choose 2}$ is the way to choice two values from $13$ (and it doesn't matter which gets which value.  ${13 \choose 1}$ is the way to choice one value to give the the first person and ${12\choose 1}$ is the way to choice another value to the second where it does matter which gets which.

For two-pair it doesn't matter which pair gets which as they are both the same thing: pairs.  For full house it does matter what the triple gets and what the pair get as they are two distinct things: a triple and a pair.